# PowerShell--Finding any and all Subdirectories and Moving them

Tags: powershell

This has been sort of asked, but none of the questions I've found have quite answered what I'm looking to do. I'm working with PowerShell (brand new to it) to write a script that will search for subdirectories within a directory and move those to a designated directory if found.

My problem lies within the following code:

```
$Folders = C:\Users\temp

$MoveFolders = Test-Path $Folders -PathType Container

Write-Host $MoveFolders 
#I'm writing this with ISE, so I'm using write-host to view output for testing.
```

The problem I'm running into is that every time this code is ran, it returns true, even when there are no folders within the temp directory. I've tried it with about every conceivable way I can imagine, and tested with get-childitem piped with a where-object, but I want to only execute the move if a subdirectory is present.

The idea behind it is that, if a user somehow adds a file or folder to this specific one, it will be moved when the task scheduler runs the script.

*EDIT*
Redirecting my question; It always returns true, and a couple of people have pointed out that what I have written will test the temp folder itself; so is there a way to test for any subfolders and store it as a boolean value, which I can then pass to an if statement that will finish the move process?

Comment: You're testing an existence of `C:\Users\temp` directory. Try `Get-ChildItem C:\Users\temp\* | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer}`

Comment: Right, I think I wasn't thorough with my question itself; what you suggested works, but what I really wanted to do was have a boolean value stored and pass it to an if statement which would make the changes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to do.

```
  #get the folders/subfolders from the directory
  $folders = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\temp -Recurse -Directory
    #loop through the folders
    foreach($folder in $folders) {    
        #copy the the folder(s) and item(s) within to the destination   
        Copy-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Destination C:\test -Recurse
    }
```

Here is the updated answer since you edited your question.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\mkrouse\Desktop\test -Directory -Recurse
#if items is equal to null, then there are no subfolders so assign the boolean to true
if($items -eq $null) {
    [bool]$NoSubfolders = $true;
    } else {
    [bool] $NoSubfolders = $false;
    }
```

Comment: I edited my question to clarify because I realize it was vague; I apologize. What I'm really trying to do is test the existence of subfolders, store as a boolean and use that value for an if statement further along.

Comment: @user6111573 Closer to what you wanted?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I modified it a bit and I think I've got it now. Still testing it. Turns out there's pretty much no way using test path to do what I wanted, I did work with what you provided. Appreciate it a ton! I wound up with `$MoveFolders = Get-ChildItem $Folders -recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} if($MoveFolders -ne $Null) { code }`

Comment: @user6111573 Great! I'm glad you were able to get it to work. PowerShell is one of my favorite scripting languages so I'm glad you could learn on your own. If you could select my answer as the correct answer it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code tests whether "c:\users\temp" is a folder - which is always true. You need to look for folders within "c:\users\temp".  One approach:

```
$Folders = "C:\temp"
$MoveFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders -Directory
Write-Host $MoveFolders.Count
```

$MoveFolders now contains a list of all folders within "c:\users\temp".  Now you have a list of folders to be moved.

Comment: Ok I see where you're going; is there a way I can have a boolean value returned from this test? I wanted to pass $MoveFolders to an if statement that would then proceed to move the folders if the value were true. I'm probably overcomplicating it.